# after clicking submit on a contact form, how do i stay on the same page in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, forms

So I created a custom contact form in WordPress, using PHP. The form sends, and I am receiving emails. The problem I'm having is that once you hit submit, it goes to a post page, and doesn't stay on the original page.

I've tried using a session and header location (didn't work) 
I also tried putting this in my action"`<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`", doesn't work either. (mail just doesn't send it and sends me to 404 page.

So I'm a little stuck, as to fix this problem. Normally I would have no problems if this was a static web page, but because I'm using WordPress, this task seems to be more troublesome.

Here is a link to the website http://www.indianpointresort.ca/

Here is the php validation:

```
<?php

    /*session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['afaisfjisjfijfjiwaefjawsefijef'])){
        $url = 'http://www.indianpointresort.ca/';
        header("Location:home.php?url=$url");
    }*/

    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);

    echo "$name | $email | $phone | $subject | $message";   


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $boolValidationOK = 1;
        $strValidationMessage = "";

        //validate first name
        //validate last name
        if(strlen($name)<3){
            $boolValidationOK = 0;
            $strValidationMessage .= "Please fill in a proper first and last name </br>";
        }
        //email validation:
        $emailValidate =  validate_email( $email );// calls the function below to validate the email addy
        if(!$emailValidate ){
             $boolValidationOK = 0;
            $strValidationMessage .= "Please fill in proper email address </br>";
        }
        //validate phone
        $phone = checkPhoneNumber($phone);
        if(!$phone){
            $boolValidationOK = 0;
            $strValidationMessage .= "Please fill proper phone number </br>";
        }
        //validate subject
        if(strlen($subject)<3){
            $boolValidationOK = 0;
            $strValidationMessage .= "Please fill in a proper subject description </br>";
        }
        //validate description
        if(strlen($message)<3){
            $boolValidationOK = 0;
            $strValidationMessage .= "Please fill in a proper message </br>";
        }
        if($boolValidationOK == 1){
            //$strValidationMessage = "SUCCESS";

            //MAIL SECURITY !!!!!!!


    // WE MUST VALIDATE AGAINST EMAIL INJECTIONS; THE SPAMMERS BEST WEAPON
    $badStrings = array("Content-Type:",
    "MIME-Version:",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding:",
    "bcc:",
    "cc:");
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v){// change to $_POST if your form was method="post"
        foreach($badStrings as $v2){
            if(strpos($v, $v2) !== false){
                // In case of spam, all actions taken here
                //header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
                echo "<script>document.location =\"http://www.bermuda-triangle.org/\" </script>";
                exit; // stop all further PHP scripting, so mail will not be sent.
            }
        }
    }


    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    //echo $ip;


    /* Spammer List: IP's that have spammed you before ***********/
            $spams = array (
             "static.16.86.46.78.clients.your-server.de", 
             "87.101.244.8", 
             "144.229.34.5", 
             "89.248.168.70",
             "reserve.cableplus.com.cn",
             "94.102.60.182",
             "194.8.75.145",
             "194.8.75.50",
             "194.8.75.62",
             "194.170.32.252"
             //"S0106004005289027.ed.shawcable.net"  Phil's IP as test 

        ); // array of evil spammers

        foreach ($spams as $site) {// Redirect known spammers
            $pattern = "/$site/i";
            if (preg_match ($pattern, $ip)) {
                // whatever you want to do for the spammer
                echo "logging spam activity..";

                exit();
            }
        }   
        $to = "";
        //$subject = " Indian Point";
        // compose headers
        $headers = "From: Indian Point Resort.\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

        $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

        // send email
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            }
    }//end of submit

    //validate phone number
    function checkPhoneNumber($number){
        $number = str_replace("-", "", $number);
        $number = str_replace(".", "", $number);
        $number = str_replace(" ", "", $number);
        $number = str_replace(",", "", $number);
        $number = str_replace("(", "", $number);
        $number = str_replace(")", "", $number);

        if((strlen($number) != 10) || (!is_numeric($number))){
            return false;
        }else{
            return $number;
        }
    }
    //email validation
    function validate_email( $senderemail ){ // this is a function; it receives info and returns a value.
    $email = trim( $senderemail ); # removes whitespace
     if(!empty($email) ):
        //  validate email address syntax
       if( preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\_\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z]+\.?[a-z]{1,4}$/i', $email, $match) ):
         return strtolower($match[0]); # valid!
       endif;
     endif;
     return false; # NOT valid!
}
?>
```

Here is the form:

```
   <div id="msgForm" class=" msgForm five columns">
                                    <h4>Questions?</h4>
                                    <h5>Send us a message!</h5>
                                    <form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <p><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" placeholder="name*"/></p>
                                        <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*"/></p>
                                        <p><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone #*"/></p>
                                        <p><input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="subject*"/></p>
                                        <p><textarea name="message" placeholder="Message*"></textarea></p>
                                        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="Submit"/></p>
                                        <div class="error">
                                        <?php
                                        if($strValidationMessage){
                                            echo $strValidationMessage;
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        </div>  
                                    </form>
                                </div><!--end of form-->
```

Comment: The only ways to stop a form from submitting is with javascript, or turning the sumbit button into a regular button (but it could still be submitted).

Comment: Note that Wordpress has it's own special way of doing ajax requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to start off I would remove that gmail account from your info (just to be safe).
Secondly I would advise you to use the sendmail scripts provided by Wordpress. 
There are plugins like gravityforms which allow you to make a form and decide all these options without making a static form, nor a new template file for that matter.

You can only change to which page the form will redirect after the refresh (the action will decide that)

If you want it to stay on the same page you can put the page itself in the action and on top put an if statement like

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

//validation, sendmail, and possibly errors here
}
else{
//show the form
}

anyway, a refreshing webform is as standard as it gets. It's just how it submits things. The only way you could prevent a page is by using jquery or javascript like so: (give your submit an id)

```
$('#submit').on("click", function(e){
//this prevents any submit functionality (like refresh)
e.preventDefault();
//custom code to get values here and put them in the sendmail function like so:
var message = $('$message').text();

}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a plugin. I don't know if this poses a problem, but my contact form is the footer, and not on actual page. my form submits, it's just the redirect I'm having issues with.

Comment: Ah, is that all? In that case you could just use a form action. 
Use a form action to call to a page which sends the mail, but make 100% sure that this page does NOT print anything. (no text) because then it will go to that page and show whatever text it would. 

If you make sure the action page only has functions (like sendmail) and nothing printed it should simply refresh the page without redirecting. if this won't work you could always give the current url with the form and redirect it back to that.

if that still doesn't work, you'll have to resort to jQuery like I said in my post.

Comment: oh and also, no, plugins are definitely not required. If you are skilled enough I would recommend not using them as they slow down your wordpress. :)

Comment: I ended up using contact form 7...kinda decent, I will try the custom form for my next wordpress site :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `ajax` form submission. And add the `insert query` in a separate file.